# Converting math equation inside a string into an int

Tags: python, math, type-conversion

I want to convert a string such as `'246 + 34'` into an integer such as `246 + 34`. How can I do this? My goal is to print the sum of the equation in the string.

I have tried `int('246 + 34')`, but I get the error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '246+34'

Comment: One way that I'm pretty sure will work is to parse the string into a symbolic expression and evaluate that, via Sympy (https://sympy.org). There may be other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Two options that I know of would to use eval(equation) or

```
string = '246 + 34'.split()
equation = None

if string[1] == '+': equation = int(string[0]) + int(string[2])
if string[1] == '-': equation = int(string[0]) - int(string[2])
if string[1] == '/': equation = int(string[0]) / int(string[2])
if string[1] == '*': equation = int(string[0]) * int(string[2])
```

Which splits the equation by spaces and separates numbers and operators.